# Jenkins pipeline script to remove all docker containers - Windows :(

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

below is the line of code I am using in my jenkins pipeline script to remove all containers.....so I can then replace container with new version

```
bat 'docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) -f'
```

But I am getting the error

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a
```

The command `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) -f` works OK in Powershell......but when called from Jenkins using `bat` it fails

Answer (score 0):

Running with 'bat' means it is a Windows command, so Windows don't know what is:

```
$(docker ps -a -q)
```

at all, since this is a linux (bash/sh) syntax!

You should replace it with something like this:

```
bat '''
  FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`docker ps -a -q`) DO (
   SET var=%%F
  )
 docker rm -f %var% 
'''
```

Or any Windows trick that will put the output of the first docker command into a variable and use it for deleting the container.

Answer (score -1):

Please try `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)`

or

```
sh """
  docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
  """
```

Update :

```
stage('Remove Containers') {
      sh 'docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)'
    }
```